# Delete query with conditions in NotORM

Tags: pdo, notorm

How can I implement the below query using pdo notorm?

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE (down-up)>=some value AND id=$id");
```

I know the below statement will delete the selected row with id of value $id. But I am confused on, how can I check the condition, `(down-up)>=some value` in my delete statement.

```
$row  = $db->table[$id];

$affected = $row->delete();
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$notORM->tablename("id", $id)->where("down-up >= value")->delete();
```

I haven't tested it, let me know if you have any issues.